# Select the Database name in iSQL plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a database but I don't know it's name, and I'm wondering how I can know it using iSQL Plus.
So if anyone could please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once connected to your RDBMS, you can issue the following command to query the  database name:

```
select ora_database_name from dual;
```

---

On my system:

```
SQL> select ora_database_name from dual;

ORA_DATABASE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XE
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I've updated my question with the result but I need to know the list of tables. So if you could please advise. Thank you very much

Comment: select * from user|all_tables;

Use user_tables for your tables, use all_tables for all of the tables in the database

iSQL*Plus is quite old and no longer supported. Do you require a web interface? APEX SQL Worksheet is current and can help with some of the UI until you get comfy with the SQL. If not, then Oracle SQL Developer has a SQL interface and a UI to click around your database.

Comment: @shepherd Glad to have helped you. Please, do not edit your question for something different. Instead, if you have an other issue, feel free to ask another question. [This is how StackOverflow works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188627/229922).

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Thanks for your help and thanks for advising me about the guidelines. I reverted the question and made a new question found in this link if you could check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627742/select-database-details-and-table-names-in-isql-plus