# Select Database details and table names in iSQL plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I used the answer of the question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625414/select-the-database-name-in-isql-plus/27625566?noredirect=1#comment43675771_27625566) to get the database name using this command `select ora_database_name from dual;`.  and below is a screen shot of the result. But how to get the details of this database found in the screenshot and its list of tables?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find most details of the database and the client using the queries against metadata tables or USERENV variables.

For example:

```
select * from global_name; -- will give you the name

select * from v$version; -- will give you the oracle version and other details. 

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

For details about the objects, you can query oracle's data dictionary tables. If you need list of tables, you could use user_tables (tables owned by current user), all_tables (tables that are accessible to the current user) or dba_tables (all tables in the database).

```
select * from dba_tables where owner = 'SYS';

SYS TMP_F_FREQ_BKP  SYSTEM
SYS OLAP_CUBE_BUILD_PROCESSES$  SYSTEM
SYS TRUSTED_LIST$   SYSTEM
SYS WRH$_PERSISTENT_QMN_CACHE   SYSAUX
.....
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables014.htm#ADMIN01508